# Qt error cannot find -lQtCored collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator, static-linking

I am getting the following error, when I run programs in **debug** mode.

```
cannot find -lQtCored 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can run programs normally in release mode. Is it because I have done **static linking** (I can run my executable without Qt Creator)? 
I am using Qt Creator with Qt 4.7.0 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linker can not see debug library of QtCore (as shown - `-lQtCored`, release lib - `-lQtCore`).
You need checked, really you build this debug library or not, then checked all pathes to this debug library.

PS. Yes, you can run executable without Qt-Creator. You should use `qmake` (into directory with your `.pro`) and `make` (when your qmake has generate `Makefile`).

PSS. If you want to run `.exe` then you should put some Qt libraries into directory with `.exe`.

Answer (score 9):

The following command would solve this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: It would be nice with a description of the problem and in which case this solution will work

Comment: Is this solution valid for windows?

Comment: @Littlegeek Its OpenGL utility library which is required for QT widget to work..

Comment: @AshikurRahman This solution works for Debian based Operating systems